# Toggle between form and unit is not working in Firemonkey project

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm testing Delphi XE2 and I create a new FireMonkey HD  Application, but  I have an  issue  the form designer for the FireMonkey forms is not visible or Available, the option Toggle Form/unit in the View menu is disabled as well the toolbar button to switch between forms and code, even using F12 does not work. I tried the Shitf-F12 option (Forms windows) but none form is listed. I tried adding new firemonkey  forms too, but none form is shown, only the code is visible. -Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue some days ago and the problem was that I disabled the `Embedded designer` option. So it seems that the FireMonkey form designer only works in a embedded window.

Try enabling `Embedded designer` option in

Tools -> Options -> Environment Options -> VCL Designer -> Embedded designer

Comment: I didn't know there still are people using the "floating" layout.

Comment: That just saved my day too :D

Comment: @RudyVelthuis-what's wrong with floating layout? I love it :)

Comment: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\15.0\Form Design]
"Embedded Designer"="true"

Answer (score 5):

For information this is written in the *readme*:

> FireMonkey Requires Embedded Designer
>
> FireMonkey only supports the embedded form designer. If the IDE is set
>   to use the non-embedded designer (that is, if Tools > Options >
>   Environment Options > VCL Designer > Embedded Designer is unchecked),
>   then FireMonkey projects will open FireMonkey Form units as if they
>   were plain Delphi units. The Form Designer will not be accessible. To
>   use the Form Designer, check the option to use the Embedded Designer
>   and restart the IDE.

Comment: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\15.0\Form Design]
"Embedded Designer"="true"